# sql output as a list in ksh

Tags: unix, ksh

I have a script where the sql output of the function is multiple rows (one column) and I'm trying to loop through those for loop function but can't get to seem to get it to work...

```
rslt=sqlquery {}

echo $rslt
1
2
3
4

for i in $rslt
do
echo "lvl$i"
done
```

but for the loop...I keep getting this back four times

```
lvl1
2
3
4
```

where as I want to get this back...

```
lvl1
lvl2
lvl3
lvl4
```

how do I get that?

Comment: thanks...corrected the typo...

Comment: How is rslt actually filled?
Does it has proper line endings?
Try sqlquery {} > debugfile and edit the debugfile
or try something as rslt="$(sqlquery {})"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the needed result in your script you need to take `$rslt` under double quotes `"`. This will ensure that you are not loosing the new lines `\n` from you result which you are expecting to have in the loop.

```
for i in "$rslt"
do
echo "lvl$i"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

To loop over the values in a `ksh` array, you need to use the `${array[@]}` syntax:

```
$ set -A rslt 1 2 3 4
$ for i in ${rslt[@]}
> do
> echo "lvl$i"
> done
lvl1
lvl2
lvl3
lvl4
```